# My PC crashes randomly with weird static on the screen

Tags: freeze, crash

Since a couple days ago, my PC has been acting a bit funny. But this happens really randomly:

- The system freezes and is uncontrollable when crashing.
- Displays weird static screen.
- If music is played, it becomes a disturbing stuttering/buzzing sound.
- Sometimes it would be crashing right at the time my PC just started.
- I can be using my PC for hours without it crashing, sometimes 10 minutes or 20 minutes, but eventually it will crash again.
- I have to restart my PC every time this happens but sometimes my PC reboots itself.

This is a screenshot to describe the case:

[image]

My specs:

- Windows 10 Pro 21H1
- **GPU**: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
- **CPU**: i5-4590
- **RAM**: 8GB DDR3
- **Monitor**: Dell

Here is what I have tried to do so far to fix the problem:

- I have run the DirectX Diagnostic Tool, the notes section shows no problems found.
- I have also run Windows Memory Diagnostic, no problems found.
- Have not done anything with the CPU so far because I have never dealt with a hardware problem before and don't want to cause any damage either.

It can't be the cable as this happens randomly. I'm sure that it should be the motherboard. Does that mean it has something to do with RAM?

**UPDATE:** *I just updated my IGPU driver but still didn't fix it*

Comment: My things to test/verify would be RAM, PSU, CPU

Comment: I presume that if this had something to do with PSU, the PC would just turn off.

Comment: You presume wrong, a bad PSU can give multiple different symptoms, if it is not able to provide stable power (due to bad capacitors or similar) it will cause several issues all over the place.

Comment: I think you're somewhat right. My PSU port is loose and my PC turns off whenever I touch it.

Comment: I doubt it isn't the case because I've been using my PC with a loose PSU port and the problem has never happened before

Comment: As I tried to explain, PSUs can have multiple different issues, and not only the "gives power or not" scenario that you seem to believe. A lose power plug can surely cause issues, but that is not what I was talking about.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: That's weird. Once I answered my own question, later I was told not to do that but to include my answer IN the post.

Comment: @DevinClark - Who provided these instructions? You most definitely should NOT edit your question to include the answer to your question.  Super User allows questions to be submitted and answers to that question to be submitted.  Editing your question to include the question is a great way to just have it closed.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED: I cleaned up my RAM sticks and RAM slots and that fixed it.**